# MSVCR100 on one computer, but MSVCR80 on another

Tags: msvcrt

I am developing an application that relies on Lua. On my Windows XP machine, the application runs fine but on my Windows 7 machine, the app refuses to start and complains that MSVCR80.dll can't be found. I traced the dll dependency and discovered that on the XP machine the Lua library depends on MSVCR100.dll, but the Lua library compiled on the Win 7 machine depends on MSVCR80.dll. This is immensely confusing because

1. The application and the lua library are built from the exact same source
2. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the MSVC 2010 Redistributable on my Win7 machine to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas how and where to begin looking for the source of this error? I'd be happy to provide any information, but am not even sure what sort of information solving this problem requires.

Answer (score 1):

The MSVCR* dependencies are added by the compiler. Therefore it doesn't matter that the Lua sources are identical; you compiled the library with two different versions of Visual Studio.

To fix a DLL dependency problem, use Dependency Walker.

Comment: I've already used dependency walker, that's how I managed to trace the library that was causing the problem (lua5.1.dll). Both machines use MSVC++ 2010 Professional, if that's what you meant by different versions.

Comment: @abelian: It doesn't matter which compiler is on the machine; it only matters which compiler compiled that lua5.1.dll. That was VS2005, not VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

MSVCR80.dll is part of Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable package. If you install it, it should work.

MSVC 2005 redistributable could be downloaded here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387